# How do I get current directory name in wx.FileCtrl wxPython?

Tags: windows, wxpython

I create it like this:

```
wx.FileCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, defaultDirectory, defaultFilename,
     wildCard, style, pos, size, name)
```

Then I navigate to another directory.
Now i try:

`GetDirectory()` and `Directory`  but they both return `None`

Any idea how to get current directory in wx.FileCtrl control?

**Context:**

1. Creating wx.FileCtrl.
2. Double clicking on directory in it.
3. Trying to read directory name I'm in right now

Comment: This question is without context. Any chance of some real code or explanation of what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony. 1. Creating wx.FileCtrl. 2. Double clicking on directory in it. 3. Trying to read directory name I'm in right now

Comment: Have you tried binding to `wx.EVT_FILECTRL_FOLDERCHANGED` both `GetDirectory()` and `Directory` work on my Linux box

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, yes, i init it in event now. but how i o it as a method or attribute of wx.FileCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your issue is.
Here's a very quick mock up, from the wx samples code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

class FileCtrl(wx.FileCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, defaultDirectory="",
                 defaultFilename="",
                 wildCard=wx.FileSelectorDefaultWildcardStr,
                 style=wx.FC_DEFAULT_STYLE,
                 # | wx.FC_OPEN
                 # | wx.FC_SAVE
                 # | wx.FC_MULTIPLE
                 # | wx.FC_NOSHOWHIDDEN
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, name="filectrl", log=None):
        wx.FileCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, defaultDirectory, defaultFilename,
                             wildCard, style, pos, size, name)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FILECTRL_FILEACTIVATED, self.OnFileActivated)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FILECTRL_SELECTIONCHANGED, self.OnSelectionChanged)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FILECTRL_FOLDERCHANGED, self.OnFolderChanged)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_FILECTRL_FILTERCHANGED, self.OnFilterChanged)

    def OnFileActivated(self, event):
        print('File Activated: %s\n' % event.GetFile())

    def OnSelectionChanged(self, event):
        print('Selection Changed: %s\n' % event.GetFile())

    def OnFolderChanged(self, event):
        print('Directory Changed: %s\n' % event.GetDirectory())

    def OnFilterChanged(self, event):
        print('Filter Changed: %s\n' % event.GetFilterIndex())



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------


class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
                      "This is a generic control with features like a file dialog",
                      pos=(10,10))
        fc = FileCtrl(self.panel, pos=(10,35))
        fc.SetSize((500,350))
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = TestPanel()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, it demonstrably works. If the down voter returns, let me know why this code fails and I'll improve it.